# Why TLE for hashing and not linear searching

Tags: time-complexity

> In a recursion, I am using this loop to search for an index which is making the time complexity as `O(n^2)`. I decided to preprocess this array into an `unordered_map` for searching, which would bring down the time complexity of the recursion to `O(n)`. But when I submitted the solution, `O(n^2)` was accepted while `O(n)` solution gave TLE. Why?
>   Does preprocessing for every test case lead down to TLE? (As testing didn't show any TLE)

```
for(int i = s ; i <= e ; i++) { `// s = start index, e  = end index`
            if(in[i] == something) { `// in[] = an arbitrary array`
                index = i;
                break;
            }
}
```

Comment: I assume by "TLE" you're referring to LeetCode.com's Time Limit Exceeded error?

Comment: @Dai Yes, sir. TLE is for Time Limit Exceeded error.

Comment: You would need to see your code that creates and populates the `unordered_map`. If you're passing an `unordered_map` by-value instead of by-ref or via pointer (preferably smart-pointer) then that would take a lot of time... or if you're populating it using some inefficient means...

Comment: Are you sure your previous code is really `O(n^2)`? Invoking an `O(n)` function in an recursive function doesn't automatically make it `O(n^2)` (are you sure your recursive function isn't actually `O(log n)`?)

Comment: @Dai yes the solution was `O(n^2)` as for every element of an array we are doing linear searching in another array.

Comment: @Dai As you mentioned, I am reaching to a conclusion that I need to pass `unordered_map` by-ref as passing by-val will create another copy of that map will take extra time.

Comment: "for every element of an array we are doing linear searching in another array" - that's not automatically `O(n^n)`, that's `O(n * m)`. It's only `O(n^2)` if `m` is derived from `n` using an `O(n)` algorithm.